# Django dynamic form choices not seen in POST

Tags: django, django-forms

There is a form without model

```
class TestForm(forms.Form):
    sk = MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

that has dynamically generated choices based on external API request.
*views.py*

```
form.fields["sk"].choices = sk_tuples
form.fields["sk"].initial = sk_checked
```

My goal is to change selections and send form back. When sending POST the form behaves like being empty and throws "Select a valid choice. 2 is not one of the available choices." error.
I'm migrating from Flask and it was working without Javascript. What is the simplest way to change forms dynamically in Django?

Comment: i have your identical problem. I'm setting form choices dynamically based on some API's response, the form rendering is ok but when i submit it back to view it has no choices initialized raising a validation error. did you solve it in a clean way?

Comment: Yes, I found the way in passing values as function arguments.
`def __init__(self, sk, checked, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AgentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['sk'].choices = sk
        self.fields['sk'].initial = checked`
_views.py_
`form = TestForm(sk=skills_tuples, checked=skills_tuples_checked, data=request.POST)`

Comment: nice! this is not a good solution for me because i fetch the choiches only if form passes validation on other fields. so i decided to create a separate model for those choices "most used" (i don't need all of them) and put them into the form with a queryset. Thank you